# convert copyBackForwardList() method in webview to an array

Tags: android, webview

Can you help me with this. I need to convert webview method copyBackForwardList() to an array.

```
WebBackForwardList webviewHistory = webview.copyBackForwardList();
```

webviewHistory.toArray or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below codes.

```
    int size = webviewHistory.getSize();
    WebHistoryItem[] history = new WebHistoryItem[size];
    for(int inx = 0 ; inx < size ; inx++)
    {
        history[inx] = webviewHistory.getItemAtIndex(inx);
    }
```